# Why I have to install same update more than once?

Tags: updates, update-manager

In this screenshot, there are 2 files with the same name. Isn't this only for a single thing in Ubuntu? Why I have to install one same looking update more than once?
[image: same looking updates]

Comment: These are most likely different updates for different packages, just with the same description.

Comment: The software updater actually shows the simple description for each of the packages.

Comment: Try looking at the 'technical description' of each of the updates. See if they are identical.

Comment: These were actually 6 updates with this same name. 3 under 'security upates' and 3 under 'ubuntu base' updates. These are from 'security upates' and same were in 'ubuntu base' with same sizes as 12.1 MB and 30.8 MB. I've installed them. But these under security updates are remaining.

Comment: The software updater might have glitched and put the security updates under both sections, but kernels do need at least 2 different packages to function. The linux header and the linux image both probably went under the same name.

Comment: @DaboRoss no, linux header is above them. BTW

First one says:

Changes for linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic versions | and second one: Changes for linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic versions

Comment: They are separate packages having same short description

Comment: Linux-image and linux-image-extra are two different packages. You need both.